# What can I do when my PC freezes and makes buzzing (earrape) noise?

Tags: windows, freeze, crash

I see someone has posted [a video about this](https://youtu.be/KmJFVgOg34E). I believe this is because [the RAM crashed](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/6b4xqm/pc_is_freezing_and_sound_looping_while_preforming/dhk51pw/).

This question is not about why this happens or how to prevent this from happening like other questions, but it about what should I do when it happens.

My current solution is: pressing the power button to force the PC shutdown (In my laptop's case, I have to hold the power button for a few seconds to force shutdown). But is there any other better way? Cause I see that the PC started a little harshly after I forced shutdown it (it's normal now). I'm thinking about force stopping the freezing application only, but the problem is I can't [Control-Alt-Delete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Alt-Delete) to start Task Manager in this freeze case.

Comment: Just a guess, but the inside of your machine is dirty.  A buildup of dust can act like a blanket on heat sinks and prevent the fan from working normally.  The noise could be a fan.  Without proper cooling, the CPU can overheat.  Inspect that, clean up any dust, and make sure all fans have nothing stuck to the blades and can spin freely.  If you still have a problem, update the question.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to emphasize again, just in case, *This question is not about why this happens or how to prevent this from happening like other questions, but it about what should I do when it happens. *

Comment: Right.  What you should do: 1. Don't let it happen again.  It's trivial to check and clean the inside.  There is no logic for simply waiting for it to happen again.  If you clean it, there likely won't be an "again", so the question is moot.  2. After you clean it, **if** it happens again, what you should do: do what you have to do to shut it down.  If you can't do it gracefully, you will need the power button.  Then update the question because you will have ruled out the likely cause and people can then assess the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Methinks the PC needs a cleaning and maybe a re-application of thermal paste. It sounds like it is locking up because of over heating issues but without being in front of the laptop I cannot be sure. BUT an ear-rape sound is likely a heat alarm or maybe a hard drive failing (I've heard screeching noises from hard drives before). I've had bad ram lockup my PC/laptop before, in my experience there is no ear-rape sound when that happens but there most definitely IS an ear-rape sound when over heating occurs or when certain hard drive failures occur. Try re-seating the RAM anyways just in case.

I'd install and run  HWmonitor (https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) to monitor CPU/GPU usage/temperature and then forcefully try to make your laptop over heat by stress testing - if it crashes shortly after or even during stress testing then over heating is the likely answer and you can find out by simply monitoring the temperature. Aida64 (https://www.aida64.com/downloads/MDc2YjVlNjc=), IDPT (https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19792), and Prime95 (https://www.mersenne.org/download/#download) are examples of some free or trial-ware programs you could use to do this. Also, CPU-Z can be used to stress test CPU and Furmark (https://geeks3d.com/furmark/) can be used to stress test the GPU. Run one program at a time - please don't try stress testing your CPU and GPU simultaneously, it might be bad.

Comment: "**This question is not about why this happens or how to prevent this from happening like other questions, but it about what should I do when it happens.**"

Comment: No, power off button is the only way I know of to end this situation quickly/safely. Anyone else?

Comment: In such cases the machine is in a locked up state, not just the application, unless it is reacting to CTRL ALT DELETE keycombo there is no other way except reset/power button.